# What does phrase "Reuse of local addresses is supported" mean?

Tags: linux, unix, sockets

In The Single UNIX Specification, Version 2 http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/syssocket.h.html claims that the param value of SO_REUSEADDR in setsockopt means:
"Reuse of local addresses is supported".

Can some clarify me that phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml).
Also a relevant question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-soreuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket).