# Closing a listening TCP socket in C

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, timeout

Suppose you have a socket listening on a TCP port, and some clients are connected. When one issues sock_close(fd) in C and tries to bind again on the same port, binding fails. Some TIME_WAIT state is seen on the "netstat -plutnoa" such as:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4567          127.0.0.1:32977         TIME_WAIT   -                timewait (17.12/0/0)
```

So how one can properly disconnect the server socket and reconnect on the same port immediately?

Comment: I found SO_REUSEADDR, checking it now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the `SO_REUSEADDR` option on the socket. The relevant manpage is [`socket(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). Here's an [example](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/setsockoptman.html) of its usage. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-so-reuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket) explains what happens.

Comment: A CloudFlare blog post may also supply some useful thoughts on SO_REUSEADDR. https://blog.cloudflare.com/its-crowded-in-here/