# Any way to immediately free a bound socket?

Tags: port, kernel, sockets

I’m developing an application server, during which I constantly edit–recompile–rerun the code. Unfortunately, after interrupting the code, the kernel (Ubuntu 11.10) does not immediately reclaim the port bound to the socket, so I have to wait several minutes until I can rerun.

I thought that properly closing the socket in an interrupt handler solves the problem but it apparently has no effect.

Is there any way to speed up the process and therefore the development cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [SO_REUSEADDR](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) option on the socket after opening it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-so-reuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket) for more information.