# SO_REUSEADDR with UDP sockets on Linux. Is it necessary?

Tags: linux, udp, time-wait, setsockopt

My UDP socket is `bind()`ing to port 53 (DNS). Does UDP have a `TIME_WAIT` state or is using `SO_REUSEADDR` pointless on UDP sockets?

Comment: Why are you binding a UDP socket? If it is needed maybe you need to use TCP

Comment: @Adrian Cornish How else do you tell the OS what port your UDP server is listening on?

Comment: You seem to be talking about a client, this is about a server. For instance, an NTP server must bind to port 123.

Comment: Here is the explanation of use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-so-reuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UDP doesn't have connections, so there's nothing analogous to TIME_WAIT. You don't need to use SO_REUSEADDR.

If you're listening on a broadcast or multicast address, you might need to use SO_REUSEPORT, so that if there are multiple listeners on the same machine they don't conflict. However, from what I can tell, this doesn't exist on Linux.

Comment: SO_REUSEPORT exists on Linux. `man 7 socket`.