# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Worklight Server not reachable

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

When I am trying to build and deploy my application by right-clicking on application name ->  Run As -> Build All and Deploy... I am getting a failure notification in the console:

> Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify
>   that the Worklight server is started and reachable.

I have first installed Eclipse Juno and then installed plug-in of Worklight V6 in it. Is it required to install Worklight server by some other means?

**This is the entire log:**

> [2013-07-21 09:55:04] FWLPL0001W: Server not started yet. Build may
>   fail at first trial. [2013-07-21 09:55:13]             Starting build
>   process: application 'HelloWorklightApp', all environments [2013-07-21
>   09:55:14] FWLPL0010W: "localhost" was detected from the target server
>   configuration. Using the primary IP address of the host machine,
>   101.218.109.86, to build the Worklight application(s). Consider using a fully qualified hostname (avoid using "localhost") or a valid IP
>   address instead. The value can be modified by opening the
>   configuration editor of Worklight Development Server from the
>   "Servers" view.  [2013-07-21 09:55:16]             Application
>   'HelloWorklightApp' with all environments build finished. [2013-07-21
>   09:55:16]             Deploying application 'HelloWorklightApp' with
>   all environments to Worklight Server... [2013-07-21 09:55:38]
>   Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify
>   that the Worklight server is started and reachable.

**Here is the entire log that i got when started theserver-**

> [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched. [ERROR 
>   ] CWWKO0030E: An exception was generated when starting chain
>   CHAIN-defaultHttpEndpoint because of exception
>   com.ibm.wsspi.channelfw.exception.ChannelException: TCP Channel:
>   defaultHttpEndpoint- Problem occurred while starting channel: Unable
>   to establish loopback connection [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring
>   dropins for applications.  [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight
>   is ready to run a smarter planet. [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application
>   _MobileBrowserSimulator has not started in 30.002 seconds. [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application HelloWorklightProject has not started in
>   30.001 seconds. [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update. [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0018I: The server configuration was not
>   updated. No functional changes were detected. [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I:
>   Starting server configuration update. [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The
>   server configuration was successfully updated in 0.043 seconds. [AUDIT
>   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application TestWorklightProject has not started in
>   30.002 seconds.

**Log after changing the prt and IP address-**

```
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_45-b06 (en_IN)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[ERROR   ] CWWKO0221E: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint initialization did not succeed.  The socket bind did not succeed for host 10.0.0.1 and port 8080.  The port might already be in use.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[err] 255  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/Anil%20kumar/workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[err] 2256  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 2850  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
[err] 1  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/Anil%20kumar/workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[err] 1  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/Anil%20kumar/workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[err] 214  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 216  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
[err] 0  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/C:/Users/Anil%20kumar/workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator has not started in 33.066 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application TestWorklightProject has not started in 31.548 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application HelloWorklightProject has not started in 30.002 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how many people are facing this type of issue and their Worklight server is not working properly but here are few steps that I followed to solve my issue.

1) Deleted my whole Eclipse folder.

2) Extracted again Eclipse folder from the Zipped file which I downloaded from Eclipse site.

3) Installed Worklight v6 Plugin using "Install new software" option in "Help" tab in Eclipse.
   More detailed info to install using this process is available at this link-

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/install.html

**My suggestion is not to use Eclipse Marketplace to install the plugin as I got trouble 
   in my two systems while using it.**

4) Restart Eclipse and check.

Comment: From where to get the zip file of worklight.could you please provide the link of it.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. This same issue [is also reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934961/infuriating-heisenbug-in-java-was-8-5-liberty-profile-on-socket-binding). Follow the instructions given there.
2. Make sure the default port number, 10080, is not taken
3. After creating a new Worklight project and application

   - Go to the Servers view in Eclipse and start the server (don't build the app); see if it loads properly
   - You can look at the Worklight Development Server console view for the logs

   [Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgauY.png)
   [image]
4. See if changing the the Host value helps. You can also change here the port in case 10080 is taken and you cannot release it for what ever reason.

   [Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnZY5.png)
   [image]

Comment: Hi Idan,I wanted to start the server as suggested by you but I didn't get any option to do it by right clicking on the Servers view under Worklight Development server. Can you please let me know the steps to do it? I am very new to Worklight V6 and appreciate your help on this.

Comment: To start the server from the Servers view in Eclipse simply click on the green play button.

Comment: Does one need to configure something so that the green arrow button runs the server because when I am clicking on it, it's opening a window to Create,manage and run configurations. :(

Comment: There is nothing to configure other than looking at the right view. Please take a good look at the image; you are not clicking on the right "play" button. Make sure that you are in the SERVERS view by pressing Ctrl+3 and search for "servers".

Comment: Here is the entire log which i got when started the server-

Comment: I have added the entire log in the question which i got after starting the server. Please check. Server seems to be running but there is one error in it.

Comment: Try changing the host value from "*" to your public IP address. See screen shot. In the Servers view you need to expend "Worklight Development Server" and double-click on "Server Configuration" and then click on "HTTP Endpoint". There you change the "Host" value.

Comment: getting error- "TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint initialization did not succeed.  The socket bind did not succeed for host 10.0.0.1 and port 10080.  The port might already be in use."

Comment: Which is what I wrote in the beginning... Did you check if port 10080 is taken? http://www.itauthor.com/2007/08/08/check-if-a-port-is-being-used-on-a-windows-machine/

Comment: In the same place where you change the Host you can also change the port.

Comment: I changed the port number and started the server but got this error-"An exception was generated when starting chain CHAIN-defaultHttpEndpoint because of exception com.ibm.wsspi.channelfw.exception.ChannelException: TCP Channel: defaultHttpEndpoint- Problem occurred while starting channel: Unable to establish loopback connection"

Comment: Uhm, well, did you try restarting Windows? Is this Eclipse 4.2.2 Juno SR2?

Comment: Something is not right with your system configuration. I am guessing this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934961/infuriating-heisenbug-in-java-was-8-5-liberty-profile-on-socket-binding

Comment: I tried restarting windows but still not working. I have added the whole log details in the question. Yes, I am using Eclipse 4.2.2 juno SR2. I have changed the port to 8080 and IP to 10.0.0.1

Comment: Also try the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934961/infuriating-heisenbug-in-java-was-8-5-liberty-profile-on-socket-binding

Comment: @Anilkumar, is this question answered?

Comment: ,Not yet... I am having this problem on my personal laptop but I am able to work in Office system. I added worklight plugin in my office system by the option- Install New software in eclipse while in Personal laptop I added using Eclipse marketPlace. I will probably again add the plugin using Install new software option in the weekend. I will update here if I am successful. :)

Comment: Problem was with my Worklight plugin only, so I installed it again but using Install new software option and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by multiple networks running on your workstation.  I find having VMWare installed causes the build side of Worklight to get confused.  It starts the server on your host LAN port, but then looks up "localhost" when trying to deploy an application, on my machine this gets the IP address of the VMWare LAN adaptor.

Double click on the server and change the "Host name:" field to the IP address of your local LAN.

I know I'm having problems if I see the following when trying to build and deploy:
FWLPL0010W: "localhost" was detected from the target server configuration. Using the primary IP address of the host machine, 192.168.10.1, to build the Worklight application(s). Consider using a fully qualified hostname (avoid using "localhost") or a valid IP address instead. The value can be modified by opening the configuration editor of Worklight Development Server from the "Servers" view.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a proxy problem. Check if you have a proxy configured in IE Tools->Connections->LAN Settings.
I had to disable it in order to make deployment work.

Answer (score 0):

I to faced the same problem, but in my case the problem was i used Jre 1.8. So by checking all the possible was finally i changed the jre7 path by the fallowing way.

Actually it IBM Worklight needs ***JRE and JDK 1.7(7)***

1. In Worklight Studio, open the **Servers** view.
2. Double-click **Worklight Development Server** to open the Overview page.
3. In **Overview** page click on the **Runtime Environment**
4. **Runtime Environment** window in JRE Pane click on **Configure JREs...**,
5. It shows **Preferences window**, in that click on **add** button.
6. it shows another window called **Add JRE** in that select **Standard VM** and click on **next**, In JRE Definition click on **Dictionary** of **JRE Home:**,  Now select the 1.7 JRE path then click on **next** then click **finish**
7. In **Preferences window** check jre7 and click on OK, finally click on **Finish** and restart the **Eclipse**

Now run your application on **Worklight development server.**