# XMLHttpRequest creates several outgoing ports - why?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm newbie to JavaScript and AJAX here. Also new to web communications in general.

I'm trying to create a dynamically updating webpage that communicates to a Python server. I have been testing everything locally and so far all works.. I think.

The Python server serves "page.html" on localhost port 8000. The HTML page uses AJAX and XMLHttpRequest to POST data to the server. I can send data to the server just fine.

Here's the problem: my server indicates that for each post a new client port is opened. This scares me as I'm used to TCP sockets where communication occurs on a single port.

Here's the server code (server.py):

```
import cgi
import http.server
import urllib
import socketserver

class ServerHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
        postvars = urllib.parse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8'))
        ip, port = self.client_address
        print(ip, "@", port, "-->", postvars)

def start_server():
    httpServer = socketserver.TCPServer(("", 8000), ServerHandler)
    httpServer.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

Here's the HTML code (page.html):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function send_receive() {
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var data = document.test_form.data.value;
                var params = "data=" + data.toString();

                http.open("POST", "page.html", true);
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
                http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
                http.send(params);
            }
        </script>

        <form name=test_form>
            Data: <input type="text" name="data" value="1">
            <input type=button onClick="send_receive();" value="Send"><br /><br />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the server output after sending 1 to 6 on the page.

```
127.0.0.1 @ 52884 --> {'data': ['1']}
127.0.0.1 @ 52885 --> {'data': ['2']}
127.0.0.1 @ 52886 --> {'data': ['3']}
127.0.0.1 @ 52887 --> {'data': ['4']}
127.0.0.1 @ 52888 --> {'data': ['5']}
127.0.0.1 @ 52889 --> {'data': ['6']}
```

To test launch server.py, then go to a browser and type in

```
http://localhost:8000/page.html OR http://127.0.0.1:8000/page.html
```

As you can see the port increments for each POST. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I feel like the XHR is lingering and it needs to be closed, but from what I've read online, apparent creating a new XHR is necessary for each POST. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fine. *The server selects a new source port* out of its available pool for such ports - this ensures a *unique* [TCP connection tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/489036/2864740) for HTTP each request and the corresponding TCP connection it established. (It is the *server* that chooses the source port it uses for the incoming connection.)

*There is no guarantee that the same client port will be used* - and indeed the same source port *cannot* be used for the same source IP unless the TCP connection has been fully closed; this includes those in [TIME_WAIT](https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states)<sup>1</sup>. As the TCP connections are fully closed the source ports will be released back to the available pool.

A different source port is *not* indicative of a problem; and an increasing value is merely an implementation (and available pool) detail. Connections that never close, on the other hand, can be a problem. Use the [`netstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) command to view TCP connections and their state.

---

<sup>1</sup> On systems with *excessively many* quickly created connections from the same remote IP it may be required to enable ['port reuse'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-so-reuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket?rq=1).

The ["Coping with the TCP TIME-WAIT state on busy Linux servers"](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html) article is a good read; it includes pretty diagrams, good explanations, and discussion of practical limits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had a look using netstat and I saw the ports acquired for a couple minutes (at which they were "TIME_WAIT"), then they were released. My concern is that I was hoping to use POST to update a plot on a webpage at a fast rate (100 ms). I'm concerned that I'm going to be eating a tonne of ports doing this. Is there a way to force a single port, or close the TCP connection on the client-side after a few seconds?

Comment: @radian There will generally only be a problem if handling *[tens of] thousands* of requests from the same source IP in a short duration. The TCP connection details itself are controlled by the network/driver and is 'closed' automatically (there are various settings that can be employed, as well as forcing reuse) - also, found this interesting read http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html (the pictures are handy)

Comment: @radian That being said, you may be interested in 'long polling', COMET, or WebSockets as an alternative to creating 600 connections/minute (especially when there are multiple people trying to do the same thing!) :}

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not do anything wrong I believe.
Just you misunderstood the value in self.client_address

The port in self.client_address is not a port on your server, but port being used on the user's machine to communicate with the web server.

Also you can check some helpful information regarding the port here:
(Please check the answer marked as the [Right Answer])

[How do multiple clients connect simultaneously to one port, say 80, on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329641/how-do-multiple-clients-connect-simultaneously-to-one-port-say-80-on-a-server)